# SQL Update How to Improve Performance using Primary Key

Tags: sql

I am trying to update a column of my table based on a primary key.

My query is basically

```
 update table 
 set COL = 'this' 
 where PrimKey = 1234;
```

But this query is taking nearly a minute to run when I have over 2 millions rows in my database, I only have one primary key.

Why is this taking so long or how can I improve my performance?

Desc of Table

```
 PrimKey varchar(150) PrimaryKey
 COL varchar(150)
```

Comment: Can you add the table definition please? And what RDBMS

Comment: What is the data type of the 'COL' you are updating? In addition to gbn's request, can you post the full query you are running.

Comment: oh, and the query plan too (in XML please)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My random guess (no table definition) is that the primary key datatype and constant value have a mismatch requiring a conversion: this means the index won't be used.

So it scans every row in the table

Comment: It appears your guess was correct. The PK appears to be a varchar(VERY_BIG), while the literal compaired against is an int.